# Como não permitir o BackButton usando Ionic, quando existir uma condição?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Como posso esconder (e/ou mudar a direção do BackButton) quando tiver uma condição na View?

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem("fonecedor_carrinho") != '0' && window.localStorage.getItem("fonecedor_carrinho") != null){
    $scope.hideBackButton = false;
}else{
    $scope.hideBackButton = true;
}
```

Mas não funciona. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa é, possivelmente, a solução mais simples.

```
.controller('seuCtrl', function($ionicNavBarDelegate) {
      if (window.localStorage.getItem("fonecedor_carrinho") != '0' && window.localStorage.getItem("fonecedor_carrinho") != null){
          $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);
      }else{
          $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(true);
      }
    })
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado @el Corleone.